# functors_sort:vector

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```
class QSweep{

public:
QSweep(const vector< vector<double> >& myPoints, const vector< vector<int> >&myEdges);

void intersection(vector< vector<double> >& myPoints, vector< vector<int> >& myEdges);
vector< vector<int> >* sortEdges(vector< vector<double> >& myPoints,
vector<vector<int>>& myEdges);

bool sortx(const vector< vector<int> >& edge1, const vector< vector <int> >& edge2) {
return edge1[0][0]< edge2[0][0];
};
private:
vector< vector<double> > myPoints_;
vector< vector<int> > myEdges_;
};
```

The constructor creates the desired data structure in this way:

```
QSweep::QSweep(const vector< vector<double> >& myPoints, const vector< vector<int>>&  
myEdges){
myPoints_=vector< vector<double> > (myPoints.size(), vector< double >(3,0));
for (unsigned int i=0;i<myPoints.size();i++){
myPoints_[i][0]=myPoints[i][0];
myPoints_[i][1]=myPoints[i][1];
myPoints_[i][2]=myPoints[i][2];
}

myEdges_=vector< vector<int> > (myEdges.size(), vector< int >(2,0));
for (unsigned int i=0;i<myEdges.size();i++){
myEdges_[i][0]=myEdges[i][0];
myEdges_[i][1]=myEdges[i][1];
}
}
```

giving E.g:
myPoints={{1.0,1.0,2.0},{18.0,4.0,2.0},{5.0,1.0,2.0}};
myEdges={{0,1},{1,2},{0,2}};

I want to have a sort function for myEdges 2-dimensional vector depending on the first coordinate of myPoints given by myEdges[i][0].E.g after sorting myEdges would become
myEdges={{0,1},{0,2},{1,2}} because
myPoints[myEdges[1][0]][0]

I tried:

```
 bool sortx(const vector<int> & edge1,const vector<int> & edge2) {
 return myPoints_[edge1[0][0]< myPoints_[edge2[0][0];
 };
```

in the public member of QSweep
with the call:

```
int main(){
...
sort(myVector1.begin(),myVector1.end(),sortx);
}
```

but I keep having the same error (even if I modified something):
sort.cpp: In static member function 'static bool QSweep::sortx(const std::vector >&, const std::vector >&)':
sort.cpp:47: error: invalid use of member 'QSweep::myPoints_' in static member function
sort.cpp:25: error: from this location
sort.cpp:47: error: invalid use of member 'QSweep::myPoints_' in static member function
sort.cpp:25: error: from this location
sort.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sort.cpp:106: error: 'sortx' was not declared in this scope

Then I tried to write a functor for my class (which I never worked with before):
The functor is:

```
class order{
public:
QSweep* o;
//vector< vector<double> > myPoints_;
bool operator() (const vector<int>& edge1, const vector<int>& edge2){
return o->myPoints_[edge1[0]][0]<o->myPoints_[edge2[0]][0];
}
};
```

and I defined it outside the Class QSweep.
And I call the functor in the main program as:

```
sort(myVector1.begin(),myVector1.end(),order());
```

The program compiles but I get an bus error message:
./sort
1 2
2 3
1 3
Bus error

oii so definitely my functor is not good..
should I initialize the object of class QSweep somehow. I do not understand how this functor will know to use exactly myPoints_ elements from QSweep class..

thank you in advance,
madalina

---

qsweep is an object of the QSweep class the one initialized in the program no.
I use in my main program:

```
....
QSweep* s= new QSweep(myVector, myVector1);
....
```

Using so this initialization for o in the class order, the program compiles and runs with the call:

```
sort(myVector1.begin(),myVector1.end(),order(s));
```

And the sorting is performed only in regard to the first components of myPoints_ (as I really needed to do) for this sweep algorithm.

thank you very much for your help! (I was starting to be really confused),
madalina

Answer (score 2):

Your `order` functor is the right way do go; it just seems you have omitted to initialize its `o` member.

Have you tried:

```
class order{
public:
  QSweep* o;
  order(QSweep* o_) : o(o_) {}
  bool operator() (const vector<int>& edge1, const vector<int>& edge2){
    return o->myPoints_[edge1[0]][0]<o->myPoints_[edge2[0]][0];
  }
};

sort(myVector1.begin(),myVector1.end(),order(qsweep));
```

The comparison function is OK, `sort` doesn't require all elements to compare greater or less than others.

Answer (score 0):

> sort(myVector1.begin(),myVector1.end(),sortx);

You need to tell `std::sort`, which you are using inside `main`, if you are going to use this form, that you want to use the member function `sortx`. Try:

```
sort(myVector1.begin(),myVector1.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&QSweep::sortx));
```

Also, your sort function takes incorrect parameters:

> bool sortx(const vector< vector >& edge1, const vector< vector  >& edge2)

To sort your `vector` of `vector` of `int`s your `sortx` should take:

```
bool sortx(const vector<int>& edge1, const vector<int>& edge2)
```

Also, note that you cannot use multiple indexes with a vector of vector as you can with multidimensional arrays. I think you have over complicated your problem :)

Here is a simplified solution for sorting your tuple Point type:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class _MyType>
struct Point  {
    Point() {}

    void insert(_MyType const& p) { 
        _pts.push_back(p); 
    }

    bool operator<(Point<_MyType> const& o) {
        return _pts[ 0 ] < o._pts[ 0 ];
    }

private:
    typename vector<_MyType> _pts;
};

int main()
{
    Point<int> p;
    p.insert(1); p.insert(0); p.insert(2); // {1, 0, 2}
    Point<int> q;
    q.insert(-1); q.insert(10); q.insert(2); // {-1, 10, 2}
    vector<Point<int> > sweep;
    sweep.push_back(p);
    sweep.push_back(q);
    sort(sweep.begin(), sweep.end());    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, from your text, it seems that `static bool QSweep::sortx(...)` makes invalid use of `this` data members.  This explains the compiler error.  Note that in the source code you provided, the function isn't static.

At second sight, you cannot define an incomplete ordering to `std::sort`: if you say "I don't care if my second member is bigger or smaller, if the first one is bigger, the whole object is bigger", you leave the `sort` algorithm in the void for values that have *equal* first members.

That's why `sort` takes a *strict weak ordering*.  You have to define the order for values with an equal first member, too.